# Копирование столбцов с одного листа на другой

Tags: excel, vba

Пытаюсь сделать, чтобы с листа `Чел из формы` на лист `Чел` копировались только столбцы, в шапке которых были найдены заданные мной данные.

Работало, пока что-то не поправил, помогите понять что )

```html
Sub test()

    With Worksheets("Чел из формы")
    mstr1 = "Товарная группа"
          Set currCell = .Cells.Find(What:=mstr1, _
                    SearchFormat:=False)
    myC1 = currCell.Column
    Columns(myC1).Select
    Selection.Copy
    End With
        
    With Worksheets("Чел")
    Columns("A:A").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 50#
    End With
        
    With Worksheets("Чел из формы")
    mstr2 = "Номенклатура"
          Set currCell = .Cells.Find(What:=mstr2, _
                    SearchFormat:=False)
    myC2 = currCell.Column
    Columns(myC2).Select
    Selection.Copy
    End With
        
    With Worksheets("Чел")
    Sheets("Чел").Select
    Columns("B:B").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Непонятно, что меняли и как оно раньше работало, но... видим что видим.

По коду можно понять, что активен лист `Чел`, он принимает данные с другого листа.

Берем для примера первую часть макроса:

```
With Worksheets("Чел из формы")
    mstr1 = "Товарная группа"
    Set currCell = .Cells.Find(What:=mstr1, SearchFormat:=False)

    myC1 = currCell.Column
    Columns(myC1).Select
    Selection.Copy
End With
```

Оператор `With` на лету забирает лист `Чел из формы`в память. Так быстрее работать с даными. После `End With`память очищается.

Но этот оператор выполняет еще одну полезную функцию: все, что касается листа, пишется без родителя, достаточно точки слева.

Теперь смотрим код автора.

```
Set currCell = .Cells.Find(What:=mstr1, SearchFormat:=False)
```

Переменной `currCell` присваивается объект - найденная ячейка. Ячейка принадлежит листу `Чел из формы`, т.к. строка находится между `With/End With` и перед ячейкой точка.

Смотрим дальше:

```
Columns(myC1).Select
```

Выделяем столбец. Но точки слева нет - столбец активного листа.

Похоже, вот она, ошибка. Нашли ячейку на листе `Чел из формы`, определили номер столбца, в котором она находится (`myC1 = currCell.Column`), но выделяем столбец с этим номером на активном листе.

---

Дальше. Не ошибка, но ненужные движения.

```
myC1 = currCell.Column
Columns(myC1).Select
Selection.Copy
```

Выделять не нужно. Вместо трех строк можно записать

```
.Columns(currCell.Column).Copy
```

Копировать можно проще:

```
With Worksheets("Чел из формы")
    mstr = "Товарная группа"
    Set currCell = .Cells.Find(What:=mstr, SearchFormat:=False)
    .Columns(currCell.Column).Copy Columns(1)

    mstr = "Номенклатура"
    Set currCell = .Cells.Find(What:=mstr, SearchFormat:=False)
    .Columns(currCell.Column).Copy Columns(2)
End With
```

Чтобы не повторять одинаковые блоки строк, запускаем копирование в цикле:

```
Sub test()
    Dim currColumn As Object
    Dim mstr As String

    With Worksheets("Чел из формы")
        For i = 1 To 2
            mstr = Array("Товарная группа", "Номенклатура")(i - 1)
            Set currCell = .Cells.Find(What:=mstr, SearchFormat:=False)
            .Columns(currCell.Column).Copy Columns(i)
        Next i
    End With

    Columns(1).ColumnWidth = 50
    Set currColumn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Обратите внимание на строку

```
.Columns(currCell.Column).Copy Columns(i)
```

Один столбец указан с точкой, другой без точки. Об этом написано выше. Если же нужно копировать не на активный лист:

```
  .Columns(currCell.Column).Copy  Worksheets("Чел").Columns(i)
```

или перед `With` присвоить лист переменной:

```
  Set wSheet =  Worksheets("Чел")
  ............
  .Columns(currCell.Column).Copy  wSheet.Columns(i)
```

Не забыть указать родителя в строке, где задается ширина столбца.

Сомневаюсь, что нужны целые столбцы с кучей пустых ячеек, форматированием и прочими принадлежностями. Обычно оперируют данными. Определяется последняя ячейка и на другой лист копируются только данные нужного диапазона. Но это уже другая история.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ. Но лист 'Чел' не активный, предполагается сделать сделать несколько таких макросов с листа на лист, поэтому надо указать на какой лист вставлять. Это же надо делать тогда вне With? и у меня еще ширина столбца менялась, а при цикле не понимаю как сделать

Comment: Дополнил свой ответ